# How to compare multiple function in Emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

I want to change a minor-mode behavior depends on a major-mode.
Now I'm writing like following.

```
(defun foo (input)
  (if (or
    (eql major-mode 'foo-mode)
    (eql major-mode 'foo1-mode)
    (eql major-mode 'foo2-mode))
     (myfunc-one input)
   (myfunc-two input)))
```

I works, but I don't want to write similar condition statements 3 times.
How can I write it more efficiently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(defun foo (input)
  (if (memql major-mode '(foo-mode foo1-mode foo2-mode))
      (myfunc-one input)
      (myfunc-two input)))
```

Comment: Symbols like `'foo-mode` will be interned meaning `eq` should be sufficient. `memq` is probably a better choice than `memql`.

Answer (score 1):

You generally don't want to test `major-mode` directly.  Instead you want to use `(derived-mode-p 'foo1-mode 'foo2-mode 'foo3-mode)`.